# Permanently obfuscating PHI on AWS RDS MySQL database with Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I assumed this would be a much easier problem to solve with Google, but I was proven wrong.
We have prod/dev/test AWS RDS MySQL db's with many columns of PHI, and I want to find a way to produce a prod dump with all PHI obfuscated. I assumed there would be a python package available but scouring has turned up nothing so far.

My current idea is to have a fargate task that duplicates our prod DB every so often, subsequently obscures all PHI using a python script/library, and uploads a dump to S3 for local dev. The PHI does ***not*** need to be returned to an unencrypted state; we want to tokenize it to a string/int that is the exact structure of the original value but tokenized so we can use it for development. Most search results return info about hashing and encrypting, but I need tokens generated. Is there a way we can go about this? Any new leads for Googling/research or completely different ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any such transformation is going to be highly dependent on your source data. For example, assuming you store SSNs, do you store them as `#########` or `###-##-####`? Theres no way around reading each row, applying the appropriate transforms to the fields, and then writing it out.

Comment: I also wouldn't reject hashes for generic text fields such as name or address. With unbounded input you don't have to worry about rainbow tables, the lookup tables for such fields will be extremely large, and a free-form text field doesn't care what's in it.

Comment: Our DBs have standards for how certain PHI fields are stored, so I was hoping to find a library that can accept a DB if the format is uniform. Also, I was sort of seeking a line-by-line method, some third party library that works that way. It's a massive DB but we could set the script running for a long time on AWS, as we only need the obfuscated DB every so often when a new team member joins. As for hashes, I guess that would work for the freeform text fields, we don't need to unhash, so I was hoping for a randomization of sorts. a la `23 Elm St.` would become `57 Tsl Qe;`